# sql comparing columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I know how to find single values duplicated in table but now I need to find whole column duplicates for different id.

relations:
  [image]

For every IDNBD i have many values in table POMIAR, like GLEBOKOSC, TEMPERATURA. I want to find columns (GLEBOKOSC OR TEMPERATURA OR etc.) which are duplicated for different IDNBD. The result of query it needs to be only IDNBD.

what i want to compare: [image] (whole column glebokosc or temperatura or zasolenie)

I have query like this:

```
SELECT idnbd
FROM pomiar 
GROUP BY idnbd, glebokosc, temperatura HAVING Count(*)>1
```

but it only compare in table pomiar with the same idnbd

Comment: Syntax error. Add a comma between glebokosc and temperatura in the GROUP BY clause. Also remove trailing ).

Comment: read the whole post, i dont want result which will give me this query

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT idnbd
FROM pomiar P
WHERE  glebokosc || temperatura IN

(

SELECT glebokosc || temperatura
FROM pomiar
GROUP BY glebokosc || temperatura
HAVING Count(glebokosc || temperatura)>1)

)
```

Comment: glebokosc and temperatura seem to be some kind of numeric type columns. Can Oracle concat those data types?

Comment: While this code may answer the OP's original question, a few words of explanation would go a long way to current and future readers understanding your answer even better.

Comment: thanks, but it's not working correctly
it's showing few idnbd which contains the same values in some row, I want to show idnbd which have the same values in at least one column from pomiar

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
SELECT idnbd
FROM pomiar
WHERE glebokosc IN (
    SELECT glebokosc FROM pomiar GROUP BY glebokosc HAVING Count(*)>1
)
OR temperatura IN (
    SELECT temperatura FROM pomiar GROUP BY temperatura HAVING Count(*)>1
)
-- OR etc...
```

The sub queries find duplicate values in each column.  The main query then returns rows that have any of those duplicate values; each column is considered separately using `OR` in the `WHERE` clause.